# Biological origins of life - Chandogya Upanishad

Tags: life, chandogya-upanishad, science

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandogya_Upanishad#Structure) wiki article says that the Chandogya Upanishad discusses the possible ways of biological origins of life.

What are these ways?

And, which Shloka talks about this?

Comment: When I first read your question, I thought it's about evolution. But then from your answer it seems more like a comment made from general observance of nature. I was hoping to see the answer to "Where did the egg come from?" :)

Comment: @sv. Hahaa, you want to go into the chicken-egg thing? :P Just kidding. It is a question about evolution, although we take it for granted. To come up with the idea that there can be only 3 ways life can originate biologically is a great thing in itself. Also, Yoga Vashishtha does talk about evolution at a large scale. Maybe, I will write about it, if I can find the Shloka again. :)

Comment: @sv. Found it! :)

Answer (score 5):

The Chandogya Upansihada says that there are ***three*** possible biological origins of life.

This is mentioned in the [Shloka 6.3.1](http://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/DevanagariFiles/ChandogyaUpanishat.pdf):

> तेषां खल्वेषां भूतानां त्रीण्येव बीजानी भवन्त्याण्डजं
>   जीवजमुद्भिज्जमिति  ।। ६ । ३ । १ ।।

Translation of the Shloka, as found in [Chandogya Upanishad - Translated by Ganganath Jha](https://archive.org/stream/Shankara.Bhashya-Chandogya.Upanishad-Ganganath.Jha.1942.English#page/n323/mode/2up):

> Verily, of these Beings there are only three origins - Born from Egg,
>   Born from Living Being, and Born from Roots.

The word *Beejam* can refer to roots, seeds, grains etc., essentially talking about the plant kingdom.